# How can I make Keras LocallyConnected layer efficient memory-wise?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

This question may be similar to [Keras uses way too much GPU memory when calling train_on_batch, fit, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890147/keras-uses-way-too-much-gpu-memory-when-calling-train-on-batch-fit-etc), but I could not find an answer/fix there, so posting here. It's also posted as an [Issue in Keras](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10735).

I have a model in which, at some point, I want to merge two data features using locally connected layers, using 4 extra dimensions for a better representation. Since the two feature vectors come from the same network, it should be much more efficient to merge locally, than using a fully connected layer. Here's a simple toy example for such architecture:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Flatten, LocallyConnected2D, Conv2D, Dense
from keras.models import Model
import keras.backend as K

def local_conv_sample(params):
    feat_dim = params['input_dim']
    M = params['agg_dim']

    input_s = Input(shape=(2, feat_dim, 1))

    output = Conv2D(M, (2,1), name='AggConv1')(input_s)
    output = LocallyConnected2D(1, (1,1), name='AggConv2')(output)
    output = Flatten()(output)

    output = Dense(1)(output)
    model = Model(inputs=input_s, outputs=output)

    model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse')
    return model

K.clear_session()
params = {'input_dim': 5000,
          'agg_dim': 4,
          'batch_size': 40}

model = local_conv_sample(params)
print model.summary()
```

This is the model summary, and my nvidia-smi info after compilation. Everything seems just fine until here:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 2, 5000, 1)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
AggConv1 (Conv2D)            (None, 1, 5000, 4)        12        
_________________________________________________________________
AggConv2 (LocallyConnected2D (None, 1, 5000, 1)        25000     
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 5000)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 5001      
=================================================================
Total params: 30,013
Trainable params: 30,013
Non-trainable params: 0


+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    1     20882      C   /usr/bin/python                               69MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The problem: in my 11439MiB GPU, such a simple model runs out of memory allocating space. It compiles the model just fine (takes a while though), but when calling `fit`, the GPU usage goes to 98MiB, then 174MiB, then OOM:

```
model.fit(np.random.rand(params['batch_size'], 2, params['input_dim'], 1),
          np.random.rand(params['batch_size']))
```

returns

```
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:676]      Summary of in-use Chunks by size: 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:679] 26 Chunks of size 256 totalling 6.5KiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:679] 2 Chunks of size 1280 totalling 2.5KiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:679] 6 Chunks of size 20224 totalling 118.5KiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:679] 4 Chunks of size 80128 totalling 313.0KiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:679] 1 Chunks of size 2097152 totalling 2.00MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:679] 4033 Chunks of size 2560000 totalling 9.62GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:679] 1 Chunks of size 2795008 totalling 2.67MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:679] 1 Chunks of size 2834432 totalling 2.70MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:679] 1 Chunks of size 3108864 totalling 2.96MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:679] 1 Chunks of size 3268608 totalling 3.12MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:679] 1 Chunks of size 3657728 totalling 3.49MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:679] 1 Chunks of size 3661824 totalling 3.49MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:679] 1 Chunks of size 3977216 totalling 3.79MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:679] 1 Chunks of size 4194304 totalling 4.00MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:679] 1 Chunks of size 4390912 totalling 4.19MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:679] 1 Chunks of size 4407296 totalling 4.20MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:679] 1 Chunks of size 4755456 totalling 4.54MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:679] 1 Chunks of size 4763648 totalling 4.54MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:683] Sum Total of in-use chunks: 9.66GiB
****************************************************************************************************
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[32,1,5000,4]
```

Surprisingly enough, this does not happen when using a `Dense` layer instead of the `LocallyConnected2D`, even if having 4000x the number of parameters:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 2, 5000, 1)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
AggConv1 (Conv2D)            (None, 1, 5000, 4)        12        
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 20000)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
AggDense (Dense)             (None, 5000)              100005000 
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 5001      
=================================================================
Total params: 100,010,013
Trainable params: 100,010,013
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

The above architecture trains just fine. Why is this happening?
 The allocation `4033 Chunks of size 2560000 totalling 9.62GiB` seems to be the problem. Apparently it is allocating the input to `LocallyConnected2D` (shape [None,1,5000,4]) `feat_dim` times. Any clues on what may fix this issue?

My version config:
Runing on `Python 2.7`, with `Keras 2.1.2` and backend `TensorFlow 1.4.0`.

You can play with the toy model by increasing/decreasing the batch size. Decreasing the batch size does not work for me, since my feature dimension is fairly big (~8k) and cannot have batches of only 20 samples... I'm surprised a model with so few parameters would take so much memory.